# onConfgurationchanged not working HTC-one android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I have not tried this on another device, but am trying to get one activity to listen for when the soft keyboard shows or hides;

in my manifest i have my application node and my activity node both containing this line:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|layoutDirection"
```

and in my activity i simply have:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard new config:"+newConfig.keyboardHidden, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
        if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
            loginView_keyboardShowing.start();
            Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
             loginView_keyboardHiding.start();
            Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

but nothing happens when the keyboard comes in or out of view..

any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because none of those have anything to do with the input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard). There is no configuration change when the input method editor is displayed or removed.

Comment: so how do i listen for just a soft keyboard?

Comment: @erik add in question why you need that, maybe someone will suggest workaround

Comment: @erik: Normally, you do not care when the input method editor is shown or hidden. I am not aware of a reliable means of detecting this state change, though I suspect there are some StackOverflow answers floating about with half-baked solutions.

Comment: i care because i have a relative layout as a subview in my view, that has to move up when the keyboard comes up. you would think one could listen for softkeyboard rediculous that you can't

Comment: @erik: [Work with `android:windowSoftInputMode` in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft). See also http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an addition to CommonsWare's answer. Keyboard or keyboardHidden changes are fired when keyboard type is changed. For instance, an external keyboard is attached. If a software keyboard is show (or hidden), then this change is not fired.

If you want to detect such changes, please check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)